# SQL - Regroup by subfield

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I've got a problem with my SQL. I have a table (named "Regions") looking like this :

[image: SQL table : Regions]

What I want to do is sorting this table with the sub_region "next" to the region. In this exemple, Québec (9) and Ontario (10) are sub region of Canada (7) so I want to get them right after Canada. I don't know if it's stupid or my SQL is too rusty but I don't find a way to do that.... By the way, the website that will use this DB is with CakePHP, if that can be of any help!(Behavior or other built-in module, I don't know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select s.id, s.name, r.*
from Regions r
left join Regions s
on s.id = r.sub_region
order by(coalesce(s.id, r.id), r.id)
```

**edit**: I modified the joined query, I haven't tried it, but would you give that a shot, I think that syntax should work for mysql

Comment: It's almost work! But I still can't get Québec and Ontario after Canada with an Order By of any sort...

Comment: Right on!! The only problem I got is the 2 province sort before and not after canada....but adding  r.name to order by works. Thanks! And my question was confuse as me so it's normal you don't understand at first glance ;)

Comment: @Patrick - adding r.name to order by probably isn't the best solution, it only works because the `C` in Canada comes before `O` or `Q` in its provinces, check my edit

Comment: @Patrick - We need the secondary sort by the ID of the region, assuming that your subregion will always come before the region itself.